# Compare two strings and remove or replace same characters in php

Tags: php

I want to compare two strings (`variable1` and `variable2`) and i want to remove the matching characters from both strings(Only once).

For example: `Variable1 : Apple`, `Variable2 : Ball`

I tried using

```
array_diff(str_split('ball'), str_split('apple'))
```

but i got only

> **b** (it removed all matching characters.)

**Expected Output** is

> - **bl** (letters A,L(only once) removed from the second strings.)
> - **ppe** (letters A,L(only once) removed from the first strings.)

How to remove the characters only once ?

Comment: ok you removed from `ball`? what about `apple?`

Comment: I compared **apple** with **ball**, i got **ppe**...

When i compared **ball** with **apple**, i got **b** but the expected output is **bl**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do workaround for this using `foreach()` like below:-

```
$array1 = str_split(strtolower($variable1));
$array2 = str_split(strtolower($variable2));

if(count($array1) >= count($array2)){
    foreach($array1 as $key=>$arr){
        foreach($array2 as $k=>$arr2){
            if($arr == $arr2){
               unset($array1[$key]);
               unset($array2[$k]);
               break;
            }
        }

    }

}

if(count($array2) >= count($array1)){
    foreach($array2 as $key=>$arr){
        foreach($array1 as $k=>$arr1){
            if($arr == $arr1){
               unset($array2[$key]);
               unset($array1[$k]);
               break;
            }
        }

    }
}
print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/dp0ui

Comment: Working as expected... :)

Comment: Glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this through for-each

```
$a = 'ball';
$b = 'apple';

$arr1 = str_split($a);
$arr2 = str_split($b);

$firstArr = ( count($arr1) > count($arr2) ) ? $arr2 : $arr1;
$secondArr = ( count($arr1) < count($arr2) ) ? $arr2 : $arr1;

$objSecondArray = [];
$res = [];
foreach ($secondArr as $value) {
    $objSecondArray[$value] = 1;
}

foreach( $firstArr as $val ){
  if(array_key_exists($val, $objSecondArray) && $objSecondArray[$val] == 1) {
    $objSecondArray[$val] = null;
    continue;
  }
  $res[] = $val;
}

print_r($res);
```